# Python cmd.cmd exit on ctrl+D

Tags: python

How do you make CmdModule exit when issuing a ctrl+D command? 
By default, we have the shell exit when you issue a ctrl+C command, but does not exit when issuing ctrl+D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://pymotw.com/3/cmd/, it seems like we just implement:

```
def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True
```

in the main class, and this do_EOF function handles this ctrl+D output.

**Edit:**

Note that this will also cause it to exit if you type the command "EOF". It will also cause "EOF" to show up in your `help` command.

Comment: I wonder why the authors did not implement proper EOF-handling.

Comment: Great answer. I do a `print()` before `return True` so that we end up on a new line after Ctrl-D and it looks prettier on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Put a guard in the 'default' handler which acts upon the 'EOF' then it will not show up in help.

For example:

```
from cmd import Cmd


class MyShell(Cmd):
    intro = f"My interactive shell"
    prompt = "(shell) "

    def default(self, arg):
        "Fallback handler for commands."
        if arg == "EOF":
            print("\r")
            return True
        # The rest of your default handler code if required.
        pass

    def do_echo(self, arg):
        "Echo the supplied argument."
        print(arg)

    def do_q(self, arg):
        "Quits the shell."
        exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyShell().cmdloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).